# C: Function that recieves a pointer to pointer so it can allocate an external one

Tags: c, pointers

How can I make the following work? The idea is for the function to allocate an external pointer so I can use this concept in another program, but I can't do that because gcc keeps telling me that the argument is from an incompatible pointer type... It should be simple, but I'm not seeing it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int allocMyPtr(char *textToCopy, char **returnPtr) {
    char *ptr=NULL;
    int size=strlen(textToCopy)+1;
    int count;

    ptr=malloc(sizeof(char)*(size));
    if(NULL!=ptr) {
        for(count=0;count<size;count++) {
            ptr[count]=textToCopy[count];
        }
        *returnPtr = ptr;
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char text[]="Hello World\n";
    char *string;

    if(allocMyPtr(text,string)) {
        strcpy(string,text);
        printf(string);
    } else {
        printf("out of memory\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
   free(string);
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Forget the line in main that copy "text" to "string", it's unecessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost correct, but as your function wants a pointer to a pointer, you have to pass the address of the pointer to the function, using the address-of operator:

```
allocMyPtr(text, &string)
```

Answer (score 1):

use `&string` instead to fix your problem the type related to this input parameter is `char **` and not `char *`

```
if(allocMyPtr(text,&string)) {
```

Just a remark concerning your source code:

The `allocMyPtr()` function already do a copy from text to string.

so why you make copy agian with strcpy. it's useless

```
strcpy(string,text); // this useless
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `string` using `pass by value`  in `allocMyPtr()` you should use `pass by adress` so that pointer should match otherwise compiler keep tellin you about ,

incompatible type `char *` to `char **`

do this :

```
if(allocMyPtr(text,&string)) { }
```